# Do I need to download Bolt for Visual Scripting in Unity 2021.x

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, version

I am currently following a tutorial on udemy from Code Monkey to learn Unity Visual Scripting. He uses version 2019.x and I am using 2021.x, He installed Bolt for Visual Scripting but I heard that the 2021 version comes with built-in Visual Scripting. So, do I need to install Bolt, or I can follow the tutorial safely without installing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity 2021 [Visual Scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.visualscripting@1.7/manual/index.html) is "semi built-in" and available as package via the [Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PackagesList.html).

It is **not** installed by default though. For each individual project you need to get it via the Package Manager [from the Unity registry](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/upm-ui-install.html).

But yeah basically this replaces the previous `Bolt` asset you had to import via the Asset Store

Comment: So, should I still use Bolt or go on with the "Visual Scripting" package??

Comment: @AviralGoel it's basically exactly the same thing but the package is probably more up to date as it is THE new way to go with -> Not BOLT via Assetstore but VisualScripting via PackageManager